# How to remove multiple "readme" lines from Related Pages tab?

Tags: doxygen

I am using Doxygen 1.8.13 at Linux Debian 9.

I have several `readme.md` files. Each `readme.md` file locate at subdirectory (over ~10 projects). I am trying to generate overall documentation for my projects.

Any file `readme.md` have structure:

```
//! @page project_name Project name
About project...
```

For each `readme.md`, on **Related Pages** tab, Doxygen generate line "readme" and line with project name. And this list of links looks like this:

```
readme
readme
readme
readme
Project name one
Project name two
Project name three
Project name four
```

If click at any "readme" line, i see text: "//!".

The URLs for this "readme"-links is:

```
..._project_name_one_src_readme.html

..._project_name_four_src_readme.html
```

**Question:** how to remove this strange "readme" lines?

Comment: What happens when you use the current doxygen version (1.8.18), the 1.8.13 is from December, 2016 and since that time a lot has changed.

Comment: Do you know for sure that in 1.8.18 this problem was solved? I will have to crack half the stable operating system for upgrade the version of Doxygen.

Comment: That is impossible to say. Why would you need "crack half the stable operating system for upgrade the version of doxygen"? Did you try to compile the sources ?